# How to Rotate a Bitmap and add to another non-rotated image (GDI+, Graphics)

Tags: asp.net, gdi+, system.drawing

I have a base image (baseImage.jpg) and I want to add another image to it (addImage.jpg), but I want to rotate the addImage.jpg first.  Because the user can change the location and rotation of addImage, I need the rotation of addImage to be based on the center point of itself and not based on the size/point of the baseImage.jpg.

The question is, how can I do that?  I can put the addImage into its own graphics object - but how do I get it back into the original baseImage graphics object?  I really don't want to save it off (as there would be thousands of iterations).  Here is some sample code:

```
Dim addImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap("addImage.jpg")
Dim x As Matrix

x = New Matrix()
'rotates in the center of the addImage.jpg
x.RotateAt(rotation, New PointF(addImage.width / 2, (addImage.height / 2))

Dim rGraphic As Graphics
rGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(addImage)

rGraphic.Transform = x

'Now my addImage.jpg is rotated - but how do I add it to my baseImage.jpg?

Dim baseImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap("baseImage.jpg")
oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(baseImage)

'Is there a way to add the output of rGraphic to oGraphic without saving it off to disk?
```

Comment: i think this has already been answered.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917294/gdi-how-do-you-render-a-graphics-object-to-a-bitmap-on-a-background-thread

Comment: Rachel - thanks for pointing me that way.  Would you be able to explain any more?  I have reviewed it and don't see how it applies.  I understand that the graphic object allows you to draw-on or rotate a bitmap, but that is actually the problem.  I need to rotate one bitmap and then add it to a second after the rotation is done.  But, I could be missing it easily.  Thanks!

Comment: you could swap the code around to rotate it first. point is that you don't need to save them you can just draw one onto the other

Comment: The important point from the linked question is that you need to apply a rotation transform to the DESTINATION Graphics, and that will rotate whatever you draw. The Graphics transform only affects what you draw using that Graphics object; it will not change what's already in your image. If you just want to rotate an image, you'll need to make a new Bitmap, create a Graphics object from that, and draw your original image on the new Bitmap's Graphics with a rotation transform.