# How to save a skewed image in C#

Tags: c#, image, save, skew

I'm taking a bitmap, cropping it and skewing it on a Form.  That part is fine, but then I want to save the skewewd image - I've tried the code below but receive a 'generic GDI+ exception"

e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpCrop, destinationPoints);

```
        try
        {
            IntPtr hbitmap = e.Graphics.GetHdc();            

            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hbitmap);

            img.Save("temp.png");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks for any direction or advice!

Comment: the Hdc is not a pointer to a bitmap.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm getting hung up - how do I get the pointer for the skewed image e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpCrop, destinationPoints)?

Comment: Are you drawing directly to the Form? If so, you should draw to an in memory bitmap and draw that bitmap to the form. In that case you'll have direct access to the bitmaphandle and image. Here is something about drawing to bitmaps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/917330/2416958

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much for your quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the codec otherwise the `InMemoryBMP` will be used thus use `img.Save("temp.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);` and you will be in good shape